# Como sumar palabras de un DataFrame

Tags: python

tengo un archivo csv con varias columnas de datos, pero a mi solo me interesan dos, la nacionalidad y la comuna(region) donde viven, obviamente las dos columnas no son datos numericos, algo asi:

```
'index', 'comuna_name', 'country_name'
```

Mi idea es contar cuantas personas de cada nacionalidad viven en determinada comuna, hasta el momento estoy utilizando este codigo

```
fa = (total.groupby('comuna_name')
                        .aggregate({'country_name': 'sum'})
                        .sort_values('country_name'))
```

El problema es que la salida no me la entrega en números, sino que "une" los países de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta en escencia es como hacer para poder contar los paises, para posteriormente graficar. Gracias

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Contar Palabras en Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/185095/contar-palabras-en-python)

Comment: En vez de crear una nueva pregunta pudiste mejorar la anterior, o al menos eliminarla, te preguntare lo mismo ¿Qué has intentado para resolver tu problema?, lee [ask] y pasa el [tour]

Comment: ¿Sumar palabras o contar repeticiones?

Comment: Contar las repeticiones, cuantas veces aparece Peru, Argentina, etc

Comment: Rodrigo ¿Qué has intentado para resolver tu problema? ademas mejora el titulo de tu pregunta,

Comment: Prueba con `'count'` en lugar de `'sum'`.

Comment: @eyllanesc Yo voté por cerrar la [pregunta anterior en la que ésta se basa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/185095/contar-palabras-en-python), en lugar de cerrar ésta, pues esta versión está mejor explicada.

Comment: @abulafia yo vote por cerrar esta ya que por definición un duplicado es la replica de un elemento existente, no viceversa. Si se cierra esta pregunta el autor puede editar su pregunta anterior y añadir la información del post actual. Él que tiene que arreglar ello no soy yo sino el autor de los post, si el elimina él post anterior el duplicado será eliminado. :)

Answer (score 0):

Esto seguro que te servirá.

```
con_paises = pd.get_dummies(total, columns=['country_name'], prefix='Pais')
fa = con_paises.groupby(by='comuna_name', as_index=False).sum()
```

Lo que sucede aqui es lo siguiente:

1. convertimos cada pais en una columna distinta con valores binarios con `pd.get_dummies`
2. aggregamos la informacion con respecto a `'comuna_name'`

Tu resultado es una tabla con pivote en comuna y contando los valores por cada país.

PD.:
Por otro lado, si lo que quieres es contar palabras sin hacer distinción del país asociado a `'comuna_name'` entonces lo que debes hacer es contar.

```
fa = total.groupby(by='comuna_name', as_index=False).count()
```